# Find $g(0, 0)$ with given conditions

Tags: calculus

It is known that
$$ xy + y = 3x^2 + x + 5xy $$
Let $g, h : \mathbf{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbf{R}$ - be continuous functions and $h(0, 0) = 10$

Find $g(0, 0)$ if
$$ (8x^2 + xy + y^2)g(x,y) = (2x^2 + 3xy + 5y^2)h(x,y) $$
I think the problem needs to be reduced to the finding of limit, but I'm not able to

Comment: The sentence 'It's known that $xy + y = 3x^2 + x + 5xy$' is unclear.

Comment: Hint: replace $y$ by $\frac{3x^2+x}{1-4x}$ then the ratio $g/h=\frac{10+O(x)}{10+O(x)}\to 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From @Andrei's  comment we see that at least one of these functions are not continuous.

Assume that $f,g$ are continuous at $(0,0)$.

Using the given equation for $y=x\neq 0$ we get $10x^2g(x,x)= 10x^2h(x,x)$, so $g(x,x)=h(x,x)$. Therefore
$$g(0,0)=\lim_{x\to 0}g(x,x)=\lim_{x\to 0}h(x,x)=h(0,0)=10.$$

On the other hand, using it for $x=0\neq y$ we get $y^2g(0,y)=5y^2h(0,y)$, so -- using the same argument as above we get that $g(0,0)=5h(0,0)=50$. A contradiction.

---

Let's now change the question a bit. Consider two continuous functions $f,g\colon M\to \Bbb R$, where $M:=\{(x,y):xy + y = 3x^2 + x + 5xy\}$ and assume that the equality from the question holds. Take any $(0,0)\neq (x,y)\in M$. Then
$y(1-4x)=x(3x+1)$. If $|x|<1/4$ then $1-4x\neq 0$ and $x\neq 0$, so $\frac yx=\frac{3x+1}{1-4x}\to 1$ as $(x,y)\to 0$. Then
$$g(x,y) = \frac{2x^2 + 3xy + 5y^2}{8x^2 + xy + y^2}h(x,y) = \frac{2 + 3\frac yx + 5(\frac yx)^2}{8 + \frac yx + (\frac yx)^2}h(x,y)\to \frac{2 + 3 + 5 }{8 + 1 + 1}h(0,0)=h(0,0).$$ From the continuity of $g$ we get $g(0,0)=h(0,0)$.

Comment: Why would you use that particular path? I can repeat your arguments for $x=0$, $y\ne 0$, so that $y^2g(0,y)=5y^2h(0,y)$ and take the limit. You then get a different result. Or choose $y=0$ and $x\ne 0$.

Comment: The issue is that $y=x\implies 7x^2=0\implies x=0$ Similarly $x=0\implies y=0$ so Andrei's path is not possible either.

Comment: @Andrei, right, so this shows that this question is stated incorrectly. I'll give a comment on it. Thank you.

Comment: @zwim I don't understand why $y=x$ implies $x=0$. Observe that $g,h\colon \Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R$.

Comment: I think he exercise asks the limit along the path $xy+y=3x^2+x+5xy$, but I agree the question is badly formulated. So if we consider this path then $x=y$ implies they are both zero.

Comment: @Mateo I think you need to choose the path that is given in the first equation

Comment: @Andrei, I added a solution under this assumption.

Comment: @zwim, I added a solution under this assumption.